# How to prevent modification of an object in async thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a webservice response object that I want to process directly, and also execute a long running routine with it usinbg Spring `@Async`.

Problem: during the direct process I have to modify the object, and as it is `mutable`, the modification is also reflected in the async process.

How can I prevent this?

Example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
asyncService.process(list); //should process all items in the list, even though the next statement will remove some
list.remove(0);

@Service
public class AsyncService {
  @Async
  public void process(List<String> list) {
     //process the list
  }
}
```

I know - for a simple list - I could basically clone the list and hand it to the async process.

But for a complex xml object with couple of nested lists (like 10 nodes or so - I don't have control over this), this is probably a big mess as I must preserve the full content of the xml object.

Comment: Consider using List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(list); Not necessary you need to use clone for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback pattern. Very basic example (with Java 8 notation but you could replace it by `Runnable`)

```
asyncService.process(list, ()-> list.remove(0));
```

and in `process`

```
public void process(List<> list, Runnable callback){
   // your logic here
   Arrays.stream(callbacks).foreach(Runnable::run)
}
```

But it is in place solution. Not very elastic...

For more elastic solution you could create `AsyncService` like that:

```
class AsyncService {

    @Async
    public void process(Runnable codeTooCall, Runnable... callbacks){
        codeTooCall.run();
        Arrays.stream(callbacks).forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
}
```

and now you could make any call async just injecting `asyncService` and then:

```
asyncService.process(()-> notAsyncService.process(list),  ()-> list.remove(0))
```

but you should take care about "two-way async" and remove `@Async` from original method.